# Add Extra information to query output in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have this query in SQL Server that generates XML, and I would like to add a couple of details.

This is what I have:

```
 <FE>
    <id>1</id>
    <pass>0</pass>
    <CONSECUTIVE>0</CONSECUTIVE>
    <DetailLine>
          <Article>Book<Article/>
          <Currency>USD</Currency>
          <Price>10</Price>
          <Total>10</Total>         
    </DetailLine> 
    ....
 </FE>
```

and I would like it to generate this output

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  <- CHANGE 1
 <FE xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xmlns="https://tribunet.hacienda.go.cr/docs/esquemas/2017/v4.2/facturaElectronica"> <- CHANGE 2
     <id>1</id>
     <pass>0</pass>
     <CONSECUTIVE>0</CONSECUTIVE>
     <DetailLine>
          <Article>Book<Article/>
          <Currency>USD</Currency>
          <Price>10</Price>
          <Total>10</Total>         
    </DetailLine> 
    </EndLine> <--add this CHANGE 3

     ....
 </FE>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not all clear... Especially *change 3* is wrong actually...

But one after the other:

- change 1: This is not supported on XML level!
  Any XML-declaration `<?xml blah ?>` will be omited as XML within SQL-Server is `UTF-16` in any case (to be exact: `UCS-2`)
  Real `UTF-8` is not support by SQL-Server at all! Many people think, that the `VARCHAR` type is `UTF-8`, but this is wrong. It is *extended ASCII*.
  You can concatenated strings. Thus you can convert the XML to a string and append any other string you like, but this is - probably - no longer well-formed XML...
- change 2: This is easy, read about `WITH XMLNAMESPACES`

Try this

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'https://tribunet.hacienda.go.cr/docs/esquemas/2017/v4.2/facturaElectronica'
                          ,'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' AS xsd
                          ,'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS xsi)
SELECT 1 AS [id]
      ,0 AS [pass]
      ,0 AS [CONSECUTIVE]
FOR XML PATH('FE');
```

- change 3: No idea what you need. Your example is showing a closing `</newLine>`, but this does not help to understand your issue. Anyway, without the opening tag this is wrong...

Comment: @JasonSmith sorry, I have no idea what you need... Please use the edit option to add information to your question. Add some sample data and the expected output. Best was [to create an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: sorry not to be clear, and edit the question, if you see it, I would like to show only in <FE> the "WITH XMLNAMESPACES ...", that you mentioned that you tried, I did it and what happens is that others like <DetailLine> They also show it, and I'd like it to be <FE> only to show it. I hope I have been clearer.

Comment: @JasonSmith Please read the link about creating an MCVE (comment above). I'm guessing: You have many articles (books, whatever) and you want to display each row as `<DetailLine>`? What is `<EndLine>`?

Comment: </ end line> is for per ornament